# How can I load the datasource for a relation in a table?

Tags: google-app-maker

I have 2 models: Applicants and Submissions. They have a 1<->many relationship. When I load a detail page for a single applicant, I have a table with some details of every Submission that they've submitted. I want to change the onClick event for each row so that it navigates to a page with details of that submission. The submission detail page has "Submissions" as its datasource.

It seems that while the relation is correctly loaded on the Applicant detail page, the app.datasources.Submissions datasource is not loaded so that app.datasources.Submissions.selectKey doesn't work.

I get confused about when this onClick trick works and when it doesn't. It definitely works if you make a page for, say, all Submissions and use a table to display some of their detail. If you set onClick to a row to navigate to a Submission detail page, the correct data is loaded into that other page. Note that for this simple example, you don't have to do a trick like app.datasources.Submissions.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key), rather, it just works.

This situation is different, however, in that the table is full of details from a relation. Again, the Applicant detail page does correctly load the details of the relation. What kind of works is to set the datasource of the Submission detail page to app.datasources.Applicants.item.Submissions. I say "kind of" because it only loads the first item and I don't know how to use the "selectKey" trick above for this workaround.

What does work is this:
onDataLoad of table: make a query for the Submissions datasource to grab every item that's in the widget(the table) datasource

onClick of row: app.datasources.Submissions.selectKey(widget.datasource.item._key)
app.showpage(app.pages.View_Submission);

Submissions detail page: set datasource to just plain old "Submissions"

This does actually work well, but I'm frustrated that it seems I'm loading the Submissions data twice: once when the relation is loaded and once when I do this trick.

Comment: When selecting a record out of a table that is a relation table to another datasource then the page you navigate to for the detail should also be set to a relation datasource. So on your Submissions detail page set the datasource to Applicants: Submissions (relation) and also make sure that your panel (form?) is also set to Applicants: Submissions (relation). Then your onClick of your relation Submissions table only needs to say Navigate to Page SubmissionsDetail.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought I tried that but I'll work on it again. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yep, works just as you say. Weird I thought I'd still need the selectKey trick but I don't. Thanks again!